# RXJava2 capture IOException thrown from within Obserable

Tags: android, rx-android

The following Android Java code is throwing an IOException when the compositeDisposible.clear() is called soon after this code is executed.

```
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.zip(Observable.fromIterable(listOfDates),
            Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
            (adate, timer) -> adate)
            .map((sd) -> (Globals._BASE_URL + sd.getDate()))
            .subscribe(url -> {
                compositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response call() throws Exception {
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(url)
                                .build();
                        return okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((response) -> {
                    ...
                }));
    }));
```

Looking at the logcat exception text, I am almost certain that the exception happens in line "return okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();"

How can I catch this exception?

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I got the following code to work reasonably well

```
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.zip(Observable.fromIterable(listOfDates),
            Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
            (adate, timer) -> adate)
            .map((sd) -> (Globals._BASE_URL + sd.getDate()))
            .subscribe(url -> {
                Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response call() throws Exception {
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(url)
                                .build();
                        return okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                    }
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext((throwable) -> {Timber.e("Exception caught: " + throwable.toString());})
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((response) -> {
                    ...
                });
    }));
```

onErrorResumeNext catches the IOException thrown by the okHttpClient. 
I also found out that the inner "compositeDisposable.add" in my original code created a condition when compositeDisposable.clear was called while the Observable.zip was still emitting. I do not yet know why zip continued to emit after compositeDisposable.clear, since it is also added to the Disposable.

In any case, I have not yet managed to crash this code on any handset that I have tried, so it seems pretty robust. I hope that it helps someone with the same problem.